# Trying to understand 'lambda' and 'map' in this script

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to understand the lambda and map functions in python, specifically with regard to the below code I have been following using the tweeps API. I have googled lambda and map but I'm struggling to understand it in the context of this script. As I understand Lambda passes an argument and an expression, thereby becoming a shortened function? Could you kindly take a look at the code below for me and indicate what map and lambda are doing in each line here?

```
#Reading the raw data collected from the Twitter Streaming API using Tweepy
tweets_data = []
tweets_data_path = 'output2.txt'
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, 'r')
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

print('The total number of Tweets is:', len(tweets_data))

#Create a function to see if the tweet is a retweet
def is_RT(tweet):
    if 'retweeted_status' not in tweet:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#Create a function to see if the tweet is a reply to a tweet of another user, if so return that user.
def is_Reply_to(tweet):
    if 'in_reply_to_screen_name' not in tweet:
        return False
    else:
        return tweet['in_reply_to_screen_name']

#Convert the Tweet JSON data to pandas Dataframe, and take the desired fields from the JSON.

tweets = pd.DataFrame()
tweets['text'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'] if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text'], tweets_data))

tweets['Username'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweets_data))

tweets['Timestamp'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['created_at'], tweets_data))

tweets['length'] = list(map(lambda tweet: len(tweet['text']) if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else len(tweet['extended_tweet']['full_text']), tweets_data))

tweets['location'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['location'], tweets_data))

tweets['device'] = list(map(reckondevice, tweets_data))

tweets['RT'] = list(map(is_RT, tweets_data))

tweets['Reply'] = list(map(is_Reply_to, tweets_data))
```

I was following the guide fine but this threw me as I have never seen map or lambda before. I understand we are building a data frame in pandas I'm just not sure how it is happening?

Thanks!!

Comment: hope this will [help](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_lambda.php) you

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically a map function is like this:

```
map(callable, <collection>)
```

In simple word, it iterates over the collection, and on each item, executes the callable, and replaces the item with the return value of callable, in the list. Well, technically is doesn't modifies the list, nor it creates the new list, but you get the idea. You pass an `iterable`, and `map` returns a new `iterable`, where each item is transformed using `callable`.

Now, `lambda` is a shorthand to create unnamed function.

```
lambda x: str(x)
```

is similar to:

```
def transform_to_str(x):
    return str(x)
```

Now, given this code:

```
tweets['text'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'] if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text'], tweets_data))
```

Let's split that up:

```
callable = lambda tweet: tweet['text'] if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text']

iterable = tweets_data

tweets['text'] = list(map(callable, iterable))
```

Let's convert `callable` to a normal function:

```
def callable(tweet):
    return tweet['text'] if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text']
```

So, what your code does is:

- It iterates over `tweets_data (iterable)`.
- For each `tweet` in that tweets_data, it calls `callable (lambda)`, which takes single argument.
- And takes it return value, and returns it, as a part of generator.

The `list()` function converts `generator` to `list`, thus forcing all `tweets` to transform at once.

Now, you can try to understand other lambdas. Probably go through the documentation also, which is quite elaborate.

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The breakdown was really helpful in understanding what map does! Can we look at the following line to breakdown the lambda function?

tweets['Username'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweets_data))

How exactly is the callable (lambda function) working here? I know intuitively we are creating a new column based on every tweet that falls under the 'User' and 'Screen name' column in my tweets_data list, but I'd like to understand the tweet:tweet ['user']['screen_name'] part.

Comment: @JimmyK Please read about lambda expressions from the link I shared at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to understand lambda is, it takes an argument before `:` whatever after `:` comes, gets returned. For ex, in your above code:

`tweets['text'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'] if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text'], tweets_data))`

`lambda tweet: tweet['text']` simply takes a `dictionary` `tweet` and returns value of the key `text`

And, map is a `function` which simply applies a given function over an `iterable`(list, tuple, etc.) and returns an `iterable`

**Note:**  An iterable is something over which you can apply for loop

So, if we make a small function for your lambda expression `lambda tweet: tweet['text'] if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet else tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text']`, it would look like:

```
def foo(tweet):
    if 'extended_tweet' not in tweet:
        return tweet['text']
    else:
        return tweet ['extended_tweet']['full_text']
```

Let us apply this to our map:

```
map(foo, tweets_data)
```

So, here, function `foo()` is being applied to each and every element of `tweets_data`

And the `list` function takes the returned value of `map` one-by-one and converts them to a list

Hope you find the explanation helpful

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you for breaking it down. Just a couple further questions. You mention 'lambda tweet: tweet['text'] simply takes a dictionary tweet and returns value of the key text'. I do not have a dictionary data structure in the script; my 'tweets_data' iterable is in a list structure. Can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Surely: @JimmyK `tweet` must be a dictionary, for the it is scripted by `'text'`, (`tweet['text']`) but python's `list` can have only `int` as index. To prove that, see in your code above, you've used `tweet = json.loads(line)` and `json.loads()`  takes in a string and returns a json object, which is a `dictionary`!
Hope this explanation helped you

Comment: To further elaborate, a `JSON` object is a set of `key:value` pairs and python's `json.load()` function extracts that object from a given valid string. Example of `JSON` object is:

`{
    'name': 'Jimmy,
    'age': 20
}`

...which is essentialy a dictionary

Comment: @JimmyK if you find my answer helpful, please accept my answer :)